# Tax rules not working

Tags: checkout, tax, tax-calculation, taxes

I'm trying to make the Canadians taxes rules working.
I already did all the taxe rates...
But, of course the tax rules are not working...
I can see only the default Canadian tax 5%.

For example in Quebec I should see: 5% + 9.9750

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Tax rates and tax rules screenshot:

[image]
Tax rules:
[image]